# Accessing a Single Blazor from Two (or more) Urls

Tags: c#, blazor

The project I'm working on consists of a Blazor (server) app and a separate .Net Core Minimal API (both .Net 7).  The blazor app requires users to login to access features.  The login page also provides a password reset option.  When a user requires a password reset the request is sent to the API where a token is generated and an email is sent containing a link to the blazor application.  A user clicking this email link gets redirected back to the blazor site with the following url [https://my.website.net/account/passwordreset/{token}](https://my.website.net/account/passwordreset/%7Btoken%7D) e.g. https://my.website.net/account/passwordreset/3e717b751997421d9a52844fdea693a8

The problem is that, although the page appears to load fine and everything looks great, none of the page lifecycle events (OnIntialized and OnAfterRender) are executing and the EditForm for updating the users password does not work.

From what I've found online, blazor apps only have one entry point by default i.e. one endpoint that loads the application and all of it's requisite components (Router, NavigationManager, etc.).  Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find a clear (understandable) soultion for this scenario and I'm hoping someone here can offer a suggestion on a) how to configure multiple entry points for a single blazor app or b) an alternate approach to handling the reset password link.

Really just looking for someone to point me in the right direction.

Here's my Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor()
    .AddHubOptions(options =>
    {
        options.ClientTimeoutInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
        options.HandshakeTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
    });

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    var allowed = new[]
    {
        "stuff goes here"
    };
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(policy => 
        policy.WithOrigins(allowed)
         .AllowAnyMethod()
         .AllowAnyHeader());
});

var appSettings = builder.Configuration.GetSection(AppSettings.SectionName).Get<AppSettings>();
// builder.Services - adding lots of services
builder.Logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug);

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

app.Run();
```

AccountPasswordReset.razor

```
@page "/account/passwordreset"
@page "/account/passwordreset/{Token}"
@inject IProvideBrowserInfo BrowserInfo
@inject NavigationManager NavManager
@inject IJSRuntime JS
<div class="acct-pw-reset-page">
    <div class="acct-pw-reset-instructions">
        <div class="acct-pw-reset-instruction-header-container">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="48" height="48" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-shield-lock" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path d="M5.338 1.59a61.44 61.44 0 0 0-2.837.856.481.481 0 0 0-.328.39c-.554 4.157.726 7.19 2.253 9.188a10.725 10.725 0 0 0 2.287 2.233c.346.244.652.42.893.533.12.057.218.095.293.118a.55.55 0 0 0 .101.025.615.615 0 0 0 .1-.025c.076-.023.174-.061.294-.118.24-.113.547-.29.893-.533a10.726 10.726 0 0 0 2.287-2.233c1.527-1.997 2.807-5.031 2.253-9.188a.48.48 0 0 0-.328-.39c-.651-.213-1.75-.56-2.837-.855C9.552 1.29 8.531 1.067 8 1.067c-.53 0-1.552.223-2.662.524zM5.072.56C6.157.265 7.31 0 8 0s1.843.265 2.928.56c1.11.3 2.229.655 2.887.87a1.54 1.54 0 0 1 1.044 1.262c.596 4.477-.787 7.795-2.465 9.99a11.775 11.775 0 0 1-2.517 2.453 7.159 7.159 0 0 1-1.048.625c-.28.132-.581.24-.829.24s-.548-.108-.829-.24a7.158 7.158 0 0 1-1.048-.625 11.777 11.777 0 0 1-2.517-2.453C1.928 10.487.545 7.169 1.141 2.692A1.54 1.54 0 0 1 2.185 1.43 62.456 62.456 0 0 1 5.072.56z"/>
                <path d="M9.5 6.5a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-1 1.415l.385 1.99a.5.5 0 0 1-.491.595h-.788a.5.5 0 0 1-.49-.595l.384-1.99a1.5 1.5 0 1 1 2-1.415z"/>
            </svg>
            <div class="acct-pw-reset-instruction-header">Make it strong</div>
        </div>
        <div class="acct-pw-reset-instruction-content">
            <span>Minimum password requirements</span>
            <ul>
                <li>8 characters long</li>
                <li>at least one number</li>
                <li>at least one capital letter</li>
            </ul>
            <span>Strong passwords include</span>
            <ul>
                <li>numbers</li>
                <li>special characters</li>
                <li>upper AND lower case letters</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="acct-pw-reset-form-container">
        <div class="acct-pw-reset-form-header">@header</div>
    @if(!modelIsValid)
    {
        <div class="acct-pw-reset-error-message"><p>@((MarkupString)errorMessage)</p></div>
    }
    else
    {
        <EditForm Model="@request" OnValidSubmit="@ResetPassword" class="acct-pw-reset-form">
                <DataAnnotationsValidator />
            <div><label class="gd-form-label">New password</label></div>
            <div><InputText type="password" class="gd-form-control" @bind-Value="@request.NewPassword"></InputText></div>
            <div><label class="gd-form-label">Confirm password</label></div>
            <div><InputText type="password" class="form-control" @bind-Value="@request.ConfirmNewPassword"></InputText></div>
            <div style="margin-top: 1rem;"><button class="btn-orange-100">Continue</button></div>
            <div style="margin-top: 1rem;">
                <SpinLoader IsLoading="@waiting">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <div style="height: 3rem;"></div>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    <LoadingTemplate>
                        <Flow Center="true" Size="2.5rem" color="#77bb1f"></Flow>
                    </LoadingTemplate>
                </SpinLoader>
            </div>
        </EditForm>
    }
    </div>
</div>
@code {
    [Parameter] public string Token { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    private readonly PasswordResetRequest request = new();
    private EditContext context = null!;
    private bool modelIsValid = true;
    private string header = "Enter a secure password";
    private string errorMessage = "If you copy & pasted the password reset link from your email please be sure to copy the entire url.";
    private bool waiting;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        request.Token = Token;
        modelIsValid = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Token);
        context = new EditContext(request);
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Token))
        {
            header = "Invalid password reset code";
            StateHasChanged();
        }
        
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    // [2024.01.11] removed OnAfterRender - no change in behavior

    private async Task ResetPassword()
    {
        waiting = true;
        request.IpAddress = BrowserInfo.ClientIpAddress();

        var response = await Service.ResetPassword(request);
        waiting = false;
        
        if (response.HasErrors)
        {
            header = "Password not updated";
            errorMessage = "<p>Please contact <a href=\"mailto:support@mysite.net\">Customer Support</a>.</p>";
            modelIsValid = false;
            StateHasChanged();
        }
        else
        {
            NavManager.NavigateTo("account/login");
        }
    }
}
```

**[Update: 2024.01.10]**

I have done some more investigating on this issue. Still don't have any answers but I do have more information that might provide insights.

I created a new asp.net core 7.0 blazor server application (just the vanilla template) and deployed it to my UAT server (Windows Server 2022 Datacenter) running in AWS EC2.  The basic blazor template behaves differently when debugging on my development computer vs on the UAT server.  Here's what I've observed...

**Debugging On localhost:**

- VS launches the app in a browser (Chrome on my computer) and the router presents the root @page "/" which, for the bare VS template is Index.razor.
- In Chrome dev tools, I can see that a websocket is created `wss://localhost:7081/_blazor?id=w-c9k5cRxQl-FDF0EgdvIA`
- As I navigate the menu items (Home || Counter || Fetch Data) I can see that the websocket remains static and handles multiple messages with each change of page.
- All the page life cycle events e.g. OnInitializedAsync work as expected and the counter button in Counter.razor (@page "counter") increments the value in the page
- When I change the url directly in the browser (instead of clicking through the menu items on the page), I can see in Chrome dev tools that a new websocket is created each time I navigate to a different page e.g. from https://localhost:7081 to https://localhost:7081/fetchdata and I can also see that the page life cycle events are happening as expected. For example the Loading... text appears in the page while weather forecasts are being fetched.  When I navigate (change browser url) to counter, the counter button increments the count value in the page.  Everything works as expected.

**Observations On UAT Server:**

- Open Chrome and navigate the UAT server (e.g. https://uat.mydomain.net)
- Chrome dev tools shows a websocket connection has been created and navigating the web application through the menu items proves that the application behaves exactly the same way it does on localhost.
- When I change the browser url manually in the browser address bar, I see that that a new websocket is created.  This is also the same behavior that I witness when running on localhost but that's where the similarities end.
- After navigating to a new page via browser url the destination page does not work.  For instance, when I navigate to https://uat.mydomain.org/counter, I can a new websocket is created but when I click the button (Click Me) on the counter page nothing happens i.e. the count value displayed on the page does not change.  Additionaly, the websocket does not show any messages being sent or received from the server.  When I manually navigate to https://uat.mydomain.org/counter another (new) websocket is created and the Loading... text does not appear on the page BUT!, after a moment, the weather forecast is displayed.

This is directly related to what I am seeing in my primary application.  When I open a specific page that is not the application root page (@page "/"), none of the page life cycle events work.  This is relevant because I am sending users an email when they request a password reset but when they click the link (that has a password reset token) to return to my web site, the password reset page does not work.  Specifically, the EditForm does not execute the OnValidSubmit method after a customer provides a new password.

Again, this functionality works during debugging on localhost but not on the UAT server.

I feel like I'm losing my mind...

Comment: Your program.cs file isn't likely to show anything of great value - could you show the code that is related to the problem you have described. This should include - at least - the razor file where you have defined @page "/account/passwordreset/{token}".

Comment: As requested, I have added the code for my AccountPasswordReset page - it's nothing special and works when running from Visual Studio 2022.  I'm quite confident that the issue is not in the page itself.  I "beleive" that the issue is because the page is being accessed directly in a new browser tab and that the normal blazor workflow of loading _Host.cshtml isn't being followed - therfore none of the blazor infrastructure is being initialized.

Comment: Thanks for posting the extra detail. In your question you ask "how to configure multiple entry points for a single blazor app". I'm not sure what you mean by this./ If by entrypoint you mean a URL, then you can enter a Blazor app from any configured URL - it's just a normal web framework in that respect. There is nothing special about opening a link in a new tab - the app will be loaded in the normal way in the new tab.

Comment: I'm confused about what's going on in `OnAfterRender` - you are performing a navigation on first load. Surely this will give you an infinite redirect?

Comment: @Kurt - the page reload during OnAfterRender was my attempt at kickstarting the blazor hub connection just like Ruikai Feng mentioned in his response below.  It can't execute as a continuous loop because it only fires once - on first render.    This didn't solve the problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that, although the page appears to load fine and
> everything looks great, none of the page lifecycle events
> (OnIntialized and OnAfterRender) are executing and the EditForm for
> updating the users password does not work.

You could try with `NavigationManager` to force your client reload the page,a minimal sample:

```
@page "/counter"
@page "/counter/{count:int}"
@inject NavigationManager Navigation

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>
<br />



<a href="" @onclick:preventDefault @onclick="Reload">ReLoad</a>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;
    
    [Parameter]

    public int count{ get; set; }

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }


    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        currentCount = count;
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    private void Reload()
    {
        Navigation.NavigateTo("counter/100",true);
    }

}
```

When I debug:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I truly appreciate it.  I actually tried something very similar to this.  I added Navigation.NavigateTo(Navigation.Uri) in the OnAfterRender method but like I said, none of the page lifecycle events are executing.  I'm reluctant to put a reload link on the page because, in my opinion, it would be confusing for the user base who would wonder why they needed to reload the page after being directed there from an email link.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two routes. Keep

```
@page "/account/passwordreset/{Token}"
```

And declare

```
[Parameter]
public string? Token {get; set;}
```

You are anyway handling the case for Token being null or empty.

Finally, you don't need to override OnAfterRender. It is simply navigating the page to another page after the first render. Remove this altogether.

```
protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        NavManager.NavigateTo($"{NavMap.Account.PasswordReset}/{Token}");
    }

    base.OnAfterRender(firstRender);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  The OnAfter Render code in my original post was added as per the first answer provided by @Ruikai Feng.  His solution didn't work as the page lif-cycle events are not firing at all.  Removing the he duplicate route did not make a difference either.

Answer (score 0):

It took me 2 weeks to sort this out.  Eventually I created a new hosting server in AWS, registered a new domain for testing and found that blazor-server functioned perfectly when not accessed through a Cloudflare tunnel. After understanding that Cloudflare was the issue, it didn't take long to find online posts that provided guidance. see here [blazor server app behind cloudflare does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75301937/blazor-server-app-behind-cloudflare-does-not-work)

As most of you know, Blazor server uses websockets (SignalR) to create a circuit between browser and the server.  To do this, blazor.server.js inserts comments within the html header and body for tracking the "state" of the client.

```
<header>
<!--Blazor:{"sequence":0,"type":"server","prerenderId":"8d48d36fcb7d4eeb9006e52b5921e26e","descriptor":"CfDJ8Ar02PTxOqdJvFu0lveBoIe7qvzd\u002BgX\u002BP76cVXZjKSm2S3ggODNmGtR0kxdT\u002B7ugD6zcHM/CL5plKsIcaTT7SssV5xeZCk/q3LK4Pr5rMHH1PbXE48LA7cfe0ba1Izngr0zy3SLAfBxoMj0lUco7bWpQ\u002BQKmm23wTaBtlas9WmZpxUaurXJ7cDyWWHbBBybaOnNRC8mI\u002B1/Tkbqp7\u002BtCV0wMSczr055QkDv/5/PRT8/9EDYjXrxSt\u002BrVzUG1SK6TxJfaNO\u002Bcj80e16EmskpIjvK1F\u002BSWyww9SwgU7TqXOGj6vfferBvP3SB8kHnNqUVQPlrY/DfyaoHm2YDDoLTIEFSk\u002BEQ9fGSEEJpWZ5fuBNxbGidrFZnp/VNbP/eoRNLNluXh1jOuLEcB4G5eQl3VtESZDqoPt6BrKhbKaBJm44GE"}--><title>Password Reset</title><!--Blazor:{"prerenderId":"8d48d36fcb7d4eeb9006e52b5921e26e"}--></header>
```

Cloudflare, by default, applies an "auto minify" rule to all content which strips comments from the html.  Without the blazor generated comments, a websocket is prevented from opening or, at the very least, being maintained long enough for the page life-cycle events to run.

To resolve this I configured a page rule in Cloudflare.

[image]

Now my blazor-server app creates websockets (and handles page life-cycle events) regardless of which page route is accessed directly.